# Jquery - when attaching to certain events, original event handlers stop working

Tags: jquery, events

I tried being specific in the title, I hope it explained what I meant. I've got several control in my web page. Some of them are quite complex, built by other people, and some of them I cannot change.

Now, I wanted to add my own functionality to certain controls, say... User hovers over a button and show him an image. Problem is, that when I start writing my own jquery event handlers for example:

```
 $('div#special_div').click(function() {
               alert('clicked');
           })
```

the original event handlers won't work.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried creating two click events on [jquery home page](http://jquery.com/) and it should actually work:

```
$( "#jq-header" ).click( function( ) { alert( "moo" ); } );
$( "#jq-header" ).click( function( ) { alert( "moo2" ); } );
```

My previous answer where I said it replaced events was wrong.

Comment: I don't think that's true. It's definitely possible to bind multiple independent functions to the same element for the same event with the jQuery binding system.